# issue with putTransient for hazelcast

Tags: java, hazelcast

I will try posting on their google forums as well.
I have used putTransient on map before without any issues -  however, in all those cases, putTransient was being called on a map where the value was a single user defined object.  I am now trying putTransient on a map where the value is a LinkedHashSet of user defined objects (serializable).  The regular put works fine for this LinkedHashSet - the putTransient complains the this method is undefined for the map.  I have copied the relevant line of code below:

```
//testSet is LinkedHashSet of user defined object (fields are String, Boolean and Integer)
Long ttl = new Long(0);
testMap.putTransient(test.TypeUUID, testSet, ttl, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Any suggestions to further troubleshoot/fix this would be welcome.
I have tried both 2.4 and 2.5 versions.
Thanks

Comment: How is testMap defined ?

Comment: testMap is as follows: Map<String, LinkedHashSet<UserDefinedObject>> where UserDefinedObject is Serializable and has three fields: String, Boolean and Integer.  Thanks for responding

Comment: pilot error - should have been IMap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pilot error - I should have declared the map as IMap and not Map.  Thanks to Brian for commenting.

```
//should be
IMap<String, LinkedHashSet<UserDefinedObject>>

//and not 
Map<String, LinkedHashSet<UserDefinedObject>>
```